# Hashtag in Integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Typing `1#2223` yields the following output in the interpreter:

```
>>> 1#2223
1
```

What is the meaning of a hashtag in an integer?

Comment: That is a comment.

Comment: anything past `#` is ignored by python interpreter - only used as comments for developers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no meaning, `#` is the start of comments, from `#` forward it is not evaluated.

Same behaviour happens for all other expressions:

```
>>> "foo" #foo comment
'foo'
```